# WHERE clause returning incorrect records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I'm using this

```
DECLARE @Year_Filter_Start AS DATETIME
SET @Year_Filter_Start = DATEADD( dd, -1, DATEADD( yy, DATEDIFF( yy, 0, GetDate() ), 0 ) )
DECLARE @Year_Filter_End AS DATETIME
SET @Year_Filter_End = GetDate()

INSERT INTO TABLE
  ( blah )
SELECT blah
  FROM OTHER_TABLE
 WHERE ACTISSUEDATE IS NULL 
    OR ACTSTARTDATE BETWEEN @Year_Filter_Start AND @Year_Filter_End
```

and it's returning records where ACTISSUEDATE is not null and ACTSTARTDATE is not between the year start and today. @Year_Filter_Start is supposed to be the beginning of this year, @Year_Filter_End is supposed to be today.

For example:

A record where ACTSTARTDATE is 2010-08-02 and ACTISSUEDATE is 2011-03-15

Or where ACTSTARTDATE is 2009-05-18 and ACTISSUEDATE is 2009-09-06

Is there something wrong with this statement?

Comment: Can you show one or two sample rows that it selects that should not be selected?

Comment: Are `ACTISSUEDATE` and `ACTSTARTDATE` datetime?

Comment: Have you checked what values your `@Year_Filter_Start` and `@Year_Filter_End` are being set to?

Comment: @marc_s - If op is actually using `GETDATE()`, then its `'20111231'` and `'20120604'`, I checked

Comment: @Lamak: who knows what date/time the OP's server might have ....

Comment: Lamak, yes they are. marc_s, yes, '@Year_Filter_Start' is 31 Dec 2011 and '@Year_Filter_End' is 04 Jun 2012

Comment: And are your columns `DATETIME`s?

Comment: @Lamak: It says the database type is datetime, and the JDBC type is TIMESTAMP

Comment: Have you checked what Year_Filter_Start is coming out at? Convert(DateTime,Convert(VarChar(4),DatePart(yyyy,GetDate())) + '-01-01' is the way I'd do that, if I wasn't just going to use DatePart(yyyy,GetDate()) = DatePart(yyyy,SomeOtherDate)

Comment: um now I'm stumped. Like @Lamak, after the further info, dates as strings was prime suspect.

Comment: Hah yeah, me too. It seems like the logic is sound and I've used this syntax in conjuction with dates in the server before successfully.

Comment: Ok, are you running this query directly against the database?

Comment: @Lamak: I'm sorry, I'm not sure exactly what that means. I'm pretty sure I am, I'm using DBVisualizer connected to the database.

Comment: @user971840 - Lets continue our conversation on chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12114/room-for-user971840

Comment: @Lamak: Unfortunately, it seems I need 20 reputation to use the chat. Sorry if it seemed like I just left.

Comment: +1 so you can go chatting :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, you need a few more parentheses I think:

```
WHERE ((ACTISSUEDATE IS NULL)  
    OR (ACTSTARTDATE BETWEEN @Year_Filter_Start AND @Year_Filter_End))
```

The engine sees this as two statements the way you have it. You need to make it one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly
Do you want both conditions to be true or one of them
Secondly
It is giving you records where ACTISSUEDATE is not null because those records have ACTSTARTDATE between the year start and today. And those records where ACTSTARTDATE is not between the year start and today are having ACTISSUEDATE as NULL.

Change your where to be AND instead of OR

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause will return a value when one of two conditiones is `True`.
Now, in your examples, you're telling  `ACTISSUEDATE` is not null, so it will return that value, even if `ACTSTARTDATE` is not between your dates.

To meet both conditions, change the OR in the WHERE clause to an AND.

Answer (score 0):

It might be handling the NULLS strangely (hard to tell without sample data).

I would try changing:

```
WHERE ACTISSUEDATE IS NULL 
OR ACTSTARTDATE BETWEEN @Year_Filter_Start AND @Year_Filter_End
```

To:

```
WHERE ISNULL(ACTISSUEDATE, @Year_Filter_End) BETWEEN @Year_Filter_Start AND @Year_Filter_End
```

Comment: in the examples he gives, ACTISSUEDATE is Not Null.

Comment: Yes but in case there are nulls, I always find it more reliable to use ISNULL.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tagged your questions with sql server 2005. Given that i wanted to point out that the BETWEEN keyward is end point inclusive. So if you are wanting only the beginning of the year, you should change your date calculation to

```
    DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your Where clause should be

WHERE ACTISSUEDATE IS NULL 
    OR (ACTSTARTDATE BETWEEN @Year_Filter_Start AND @Year_Filter_End)

Answer (score 0):

your where query should be

```
WHERE ACTISSUEDATE is null 
    OR (ACTISSUEDATE is not null 
    and ACTSTARTDATE BETWEEN @Year_Filter_Start AND @Year_Filter_End)
```

hope this works...